# Incompatibility between "breqn" package and bold box symbol (\Box)

Tags: bold, breqn

Using a bold \Box symbol from the *amssymb* package leads to a strange output showing three consecutive bold box symbols of decreasing size when *breqn* package was loaded. This effect appears with the \bm{} command of the *bm* package as well as \boldsymbol{} from *amssymb*. MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{article}  

\usepackage{amssymb}        % Math symbols
\usepackage{bm}                 % Access bold symbols in maths mode
\usepackage{breqn}      % Automatic line-breaking of displayed math expressions

\begin{document}

$\Box$\\
$\bm{\Box}$\\
$\boldsymbol{\Box}$

\end{document}
```

Output without *breqn*:

[image]

Ouput with *breqn* package loaded:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to the site.  Your MWE does not compile without error.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 1):

Double embrace the `\Box` will allow compilation, though I can't say the boxes are emboldened.  What was goal?  Bold boxes, or mere compilation?  For bold boxes, see **Workaround** below.

```
\documentclass[]{article}  

\usepackage{amssymb}        % Math symbols
\usepackage{bm}                 % Access bold symbols in maths mode
\usepackage{breqn}      % Automatic line-breaking of displayed math expressions

\begin{document}

$\Box$\\
$\bm{{\Box}}$\\
$\boldsymbol{{\Box}}$

\end{document}
```

**WORKAROUND:**

Use `\fakebold` for the box:

```
\documentclass[]{article}  

\usepackage{amssymb}        % Math symbols
\usepackage{bm}                 % Access bold symbols in maths mode
\usepackage{breqn}      % Automatic line-breaking of displayed math expression
\usepackage{scalerel}
\newlength\bshft
\bshft=.25pt\relax
\def\fakebold#1{\ThisStyle{\ooalign{\raisebox{\bshft}{$\SavedStyle#1$}\cr%
  \kern-\bshft$\SavedStyle#1$\cr%
  \kern\bshft$\SavedStyle#1$}}}
\begin{document}

$\Box$\\
$\fakebold{\Box}$\\

\end{document}
```

[image]